# First layer issue with new filament

Tags: pla, prusa-i3, fdm

My settings were fine but after switching to a new brand of PLA I seem to be getting issues with the first layer.

[image: Photo of the first layer of a 3D printed model showing problems with adhesion and lifting from the build plate]

My previous filament had a print temp between 200 °C and 230 °C. My current settings have the first layer printing at 216 °C and then reducing to 202 °C for all the other layers. On the new filament, I see it has a printing temperature of 205 °C to 220 °C.

I am using the heatbed steel sheet by prusa3d.com that originally comes with the printer I have (prusa-i3 mk3). This heatbed attaches magnetically and has a smooth surface. I do also have a second heatbed, unopened, that originally came with the printer as well. This second one has a textured surface and is unused.

Considering the difference in the ranges of the filaments and my current settings, I suspect that the change I need to make would be to reduce the first layer's temperature and increase the temperature for all other layers. Does that seem correct? What else might I try?

Comment: It might be useful to know what kind of buildplate/bed you have. Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: AFAIK, having a too-low temperature on the first layer is what causes adhesion problems; and it looks as though that is what you are experiencing.

Comment: I updated with your suggestions @agarza. I will try a higher temperature for the first layer.

Comment: Wait...  what's your bed temp? I don't see that in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's 60 °C for the bed. I also wipe with isopropyl alcohol before each print

Comment: Have you tried just bumping it up to ~70 °C for the first layer? I generally keep my hotend at 200 °C and start my bed at 70 °C (Dropping to 60 °C after the first few layers)

Comment: So I changed a few things. I increased the first layer higher very slightly, increased the bed temp on first layer as you recommended, and also increased the print temp 3 degrees. These changes so far have had a positive effect on the first layer in the print I just started

Comment: @JordanKlaers How'd the settings changes end up working out?

Comment: This first print had lumps but it got past and had an otherwise reasonable quality at the end. Second print with no changes had almost zero lumps and a 9/10 finish